# Determining if a string contains any of the value that is present in an array in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a simple ruby question. I have an array of strings. I'd like to determine if a variable contains any of the string present in that array.

As an example

Lets say

`my_string = "testing.facebook.com"`

`array = ["google.com","facebook.com","github.com"]`

Then I need to check whether my_string has any one of value that is present in the array.

For above scenario It will return true since "facebook.com" is present in my_string

I have tried below code

This below code will work but i don't think this is an optimized way

```
if my_string.include?("google.com") || my_string.include?("facebook.com") || my_string.include?("github.com")
// execute something
end
```

Please provide a optimized solution or a better way through which i can do this

Comment: I wouldn't advise it, for performance reasons, but you could also write `"testing.facebook.com".match?(r) #=> true`, where `arr = %w| google.com facebook.com github.com |; r = Regexp.union(arr) #=> /google\.com|facebook\.com|github\.com/`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I would write it:

```
my_string = "testing.facebook.com"
array = ["google.com","facebook.com","github.com"]

array.any? { |item| my_string.include?(item) }
```

This uses [`Enumerable#any?`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/any%3F).

`Enumerable` is a module which is included in the `Array` class, amongst others.

Answer (score 1):

[Tom Lord's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57198666/3092183) is perfectly correct, but here is an additional tool in Ruby's belt.

You can use [`Enumerable#detect`](https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_5_5/Enumerable/detect) to get the element that matched, if any.

```rb
def match(string)
  %w[google.com facebook.com github.com].detect { |item| string.include?(item) }
end

match('testing.facebook.com')
# => "facebook.com"

match('stackoverflow.com')
# => nil
```

Comment: One could also use [Array#index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-index), but both `detect` and `index` return a truthy value or `nil`, whereas `include?` returns `true` or `false`, which reads better.

Comment: Which reads better, but doesn't allow you to know what item matched, which you *might* want in some cases.